# What does "avoid multiple Kudu clients per cluster" mean?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kudu

I am looking at kudu's documentation.

Below is a partial description of kudu-spark.

https://kudu.apache.org/docs/developing.html#_avoid_multiple_kudu_clients_per_cluster

> #### Avoid multiple Kudu clients per cluster.
>
> One common Kudu-Spark coding error is instantiating extra `KuduClient` objects. In kudu-spark, a `KuduClient` is owned by the `KuduContext`. Spark application code should not create another `KuduClient` connecting to the same cluster. Instead, application code should use the `KuduContext` to access a `KuduClient` using `KuduContext#syncClient`.
>
> To diagnose multiple `KuduClient` instances in a Spark job, look for signs in the logs of the master being overloaded by many `GetTableLocations` or `GetTabletLocations` requests coming from different clients, usually around the same time. This symptom is especially likely in Spark Streaming code, where creating a `KuduClient` per task will result in periodic waves of master requests from new clients.

Does this mean that I can only run one kudu-spark task at a time?

If I have a spark-streaming program that is always writing data to the kudu,
How can I connect to kudu with other spark programs?

Comment: If the guidance is specifically about in a single application,  That is no problem.

But the documentation says "Avoid multiple Kudu clients **per cluster**". So I want to confirm this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more clear statement of "avoid multiple Kudu clients per cluster" is "avoid multiple Kudu clients per spark application".

> Instead, application code should use the KuduContext to access a KuduClient using KuduContext#syncClient.

Comment: I think I stated that

Answer (score 0):

In a non-Spark program you use a KUDU Client for accessing KUDU. With a Spark App you use a KUDU Context that has such a Client already, for that KUDU cluster.

> Simple JAVA program requires a KUDU Client using JAVA API and maven
>   approach.

```
KuduClient kuduClient = new KuduClientBuilder("kudu-master-hostname").build();
```

See http://harshj.com/writing-a-simple-kudu-java-api-program/

> Spark / Scala program of which many can be running at the same time
>   against the same Cluster using Spark KUDU Integration. Snippet
>   borrowed from official guide as quite some time ago I looked at this.

```
import org.apache.kudu.client._
import collection.JavaConverters._

// Read a table from Kudu
val df = spark.read
              .options(Map("kudu.master" -> "kudu.master:7051", "kudu.table" -> "kudu_table"))
              .format("kudu").load

// Query using the Spark API...
df.select("id").filter("id >= 5").show()

// ...or register a temporary table and use SQL
df.registerTempTable("kudu_table")
val filteredDF = spark.sql("select id from kudu_table where id >= 5").show()

// Use KuduContext to create, delete, or write to Kudu tables
val kuduContext = new KuduContext("kudu.master:7051", spark.sparkContext)

// Create a new Kudu table from a dataframe schema
// NB: No rows from the dataframe are inserted into the table
kuduContext.createTable("test_table", df.schema, Seq("key"),
                        new CreateTableOptions()
                      .setNumReplicas(1)
                      .addHashPartitions(List("key").asJava, 3))

// Insert data
kuduContext.insertRows(df, "test_table")
```

See https://kudu.apache.org/docs/developing.html

Comment: If I have two spark program, then I have two kuduContext object. But the document saids "Avoid multiple kudu clients per cluster". How could I can do?

Comment: That is not an issue here.

Comment: Each Spark program has a single KUDU context. That is fine, else it would be a very strange concept.

Comment: I grant you it is poorly explained.

Comment: To diagnose multiple KuduClient instances in a Spark job...  that is in the text